# Creating iframe and posting parameters

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want to post parameters to `iframe`, which I create dynamically. The code now looks like this:

```
    var iframe=document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.setAttribute('frameborder', 0);
    iframe.setAttribute('scrolling', 'no');
    iframe.setAttribute('src', 'page.php?param1=1&param2=2');
    mytabpanel.add({
        title:'Tab 1',
        contentEl:iframe,
        closable:true,
        layout:'fit'
    });
```

In `page.php` I can access `param1` and `param2`, but I do not know how can I post a long list of parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a hidden form with `standardSubmit:true` and with target pointing to that iframe. Then you submit the form:

```
form.submit({params:{
     p1:'value1'
    ,p2:'value2'
    // etc
}});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will check it tomorrow. But could you, please, advise me, where should I do this submission? I guess, just before I add my iframe to the tabpanel.

Comment: No, iframe must exist before you submit, otherwise it cannot be the target for the form.